# PhpStorm и макросы. Как по-человечески подружить макросы и автодополнение/автозакрытие тегов?

Tags: phpstorm, макросы

Добрый день.
Перехожу с Notepad++ на PhpStorm, столкнулся с очень неприятной проблемой.
В Notepad++ все необходимые куски кода я вешал на макросы, работали они корректно и стабильно. В PhpStorm я не могу нормально пользоваться макросами. Приведу пример:

Скрипт подключения jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

если писать его (аккуратно!!!) со всеми включёнными автозаполнениями при вызове макроса выдаёт следующее:

```
<script type=text/javascript

 src=jquery-1.11.1.min.js

>
```

Если я отключаю все автозаполения (убираю все галочки в Settings - Editor - Smart Keys), аккуратно записываю макрос, да, он работает нормально, но только включаю автозаполнения - и опять криво выводит:

либо так: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script></script>`

либо так: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></`

И второе - не могу полностью отключить автозавершение тегов, при всех отключённых галочках в Settings - Editor - Smart Keys при вводе кода

```
<script></
```

выдаёт код

```
<script></script>
```